# I've got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space testing ActiveMQ by JMeter on Linux build agent

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I run JMeter test for ActiveMQ using Linux build agent I've got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Detailed log:

```
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124) ~
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448) 
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.extractContent(SubscriberSampler.java:282) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.SubscriberSampler.sample(SubscriberSampler.java:186) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.3
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.BaseJMSSampler.sample(BaseJMSSampler.java:98) ~
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:635) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
```

I've already allocated maximum HEAP memory (`-Xmx8g`), but it doesn't help. **Yet the same test with the same configuration on Windows build agent passed without Out of memory error.**

How can it be handled? Maybe some configuration should be done for Linux machine?
[image: logged info]

[image: build step config]

[image: checked memory usage by JSR223Sampler]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after updating Java to 11 version on Linux machines.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Heap setting gets applied on Linux?

You can check it my creating a simple test plan with single [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using the following code:

```
println('Max heap size: ' + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + ' megabytes')
```

[image]

and when you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) you will see the current maximum JVM heap size printed:

[image]

In order to make the change permanent amend [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter#L166) in `jmeter` startup script according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for answer! 
But I can't check it in this way. Cause I run JMeter tests through TeamCity by remote Linux build agent. 
I make some changes in build steps and in the beginning of test run I can see how much memory is used in logs. Added screenshots above.

Comment: I've added JSR223 Sampler into my existing test and run it n TeamCity and got the log with needed info. As log said 8192mb are used for my test. Added screenshots above.